# Grab unique tuples in python list, irrespective of order

Tags: python, list, numpy, duplicates

I have a python list:

```
[ (2,2),(2,3),(1,4),(2,2), etc...]
```

What I need is some kind of function that reduces it to its unique components... which would be, in the above list:

```
[ (2,2),(2,3),(1,4) ]
```

---

numpy unique does not quite do this.   I can think of a way to do it--convert my tuples to numbers, `[22,23,14,etc.]`, find the uniques, and work back from there...but I don't know if the complexity won't get out of hand.  Is there a function that will do what I am trying to do with tuples?

---

Here is a sample of code that demonstrates the problem:

```
 import numpy as np

 x = [(2,2),(2,2),(2,3)]
 y = np.unique(x)
```

> returns: y: [2 3]

And here is the implementation of the solution that demonstrates the fix:

```
 x = [(2,2),(2,2),(2,3)]
 y = list(set(x))
```

> returns y: [(2,2),(2,3)]

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: However you'd *"find the uniques"* of the numbers, just *try that with tuples*. Why do you think it would be any different?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ran it with numpy on the tuples; didn't work.

Comment: So why haven't you supplied a [mcve] of that code and a more specific problem description than *"didn't work"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, looking at the link you specified, I quote, "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be…"


I got amazing answers within minutes, without posting a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."  According to the document, if I am satisfied with the quality of the answers, there is no problem. But I included it anyway.

Comment: The fact that you got answers doesn't make the first revision of this question any better, and it doesn't mean you can't improve when you write your next question; show your working up front in the future, please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could simply do

```
y = np.unique(x, axis=0)
z = [] 
for i in y:
   z.append(tuple(i))
```

The reason is that a list of tuples is interpreted by numpy as a 2D array. By setting axis=0, you'd be asking numpy not to flatten the array and return unique rows.

Comment: This spits out a 2-D array giving what you want. If you want exactly a list of tuples, then consider the edited version of my answer.

Comment: I think this is more in line with what I was going for using np.unique

Comment: nice solution, can make it even shorter using list comprehension: [tuple(i) for i in np.unique(x, axis=0)]

Comment: What if our original list is something like this? [(1, [[3, 3, 3], 3, 3]),
 (2, [[4, 4, 4], 4, 4]),
 (3, [[5, 5, 5], 5, 5]),
 (1, [[3, 3, 3], 3, 3])]?

Answer (score 38):

**If order does not matter**

If the order of the result is not critical, you can convert your list to a set (because tuples are hashable) and convert the set back to a list:

```
>>> l = [(2,2),(2,3),(1,4),(2,2)]
>>> list(set(l))
[(2, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2)]
```

**If order matters**

(UPDATE)

As of CPython 3.6 (or any Python 3.7 version) regular dictionaries remember their insertion order, so you can simply issue.

```
>>> l = [(2,2),(2,3),(1,4),(2,2)]
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(l))
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (1, 4)]
```

---

(OLD ANSWER)

If the order is important, the canonical way to filter the duplicates is this:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> result = []
>>> for item in l:
...     if item not in seen:
...         seen.add(item)
...         result.append(item)
... 
>>> result
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (1, 4)]
```

Finally, a little slower and a bit more hackish, you can abuse an `OrderedDict` as an ordered set:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(l).keys() # or list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(l)) if using a version where keys() does not return a list
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (1, 4)]
```

Answer (score 12):

Using a `set` will remove duplicates, and you create a `list` from it afterwards:

```
>>> list(set([ (2,2),(2,3),(1,4),(2,2) ]))
[(2, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 6):

`set()` will remove all duplicates, and you can then put it back to a list:

```
unique = list(set(mylist))
```

Using `set()`, however, will kill your ordering.  If the order matters, you can use a list comprehension that checks if the value already exists earlier in the list:

```
unique = [v for i,v in enumerate(mylist) if v not in mylist[:i]]
```

That solution is a little slow, however, so you can do it like this:

```
unique = []
for tup in mylist:
    if tup not in unique:
        unique.append(tup)
```

Comment: The second solution is slow for large lists, though, because `list.__contains__` is O(n).

Comment: Is there any way to see if something has been used before besides seeing if it is in a list?

Comment: Yes, storing what has been seen in a set :) - the difference is that the set has an O(1) membership test.