# Python: Find all symetrics pairs in Dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with columns let's call them A and B, I want to find all symetrics pairs for example if :

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2 , 3], 'B':[2, 1, 3]})
```

I want to return all pairs like here I will get (I actually don't need both only (2,1) or (2,1) is enough)

```
(1,2) and (2,1)
```

I have first tried an algorithm which works but is really slow in my dataframe of length 26325 after 10 minute it wasn't finished

```
listTuples = list()
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    listTuples.append((row["A"], row["B"])) # convert to a list of tuple

answer = [(x, y) for (x, y) in listTuples if (y, x) in listTuples]
```

Comment: Do the pairs have to be adjacent to each other? (row i and row i+1)  Or can they occur 2+ rows apart?

Answer (score 0):

In general you pretty much never have to iterate over rows in a pandas dataframe. In this case, you could speed things up with

```
listTuples = zip(df.A,df.B)
```

If that's the part of your code that is running slowly, that should solve your problem.

Your list comprehension step looks efficient to me... your problem could be that you have many duplicate entries in the list that you continually check. Start by picking out only the unique ones, and then running your list comprehension.

Also see [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975441/grab-unique-tuples-in-python-list-irrespective-of-order) about picking unique tuples from a list of tuples in python.