# Remove partially duplicate tuples from list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples and need to delete tuples if its 1st item is matching with 1st item of other tuples in the list. 3rd item may or may not be the same, so I cannot use set (I have seen this question - [Grab unique tuples in python list, irrespective of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975441/grab-unique-tuples-in-python-list-irrespective-of-order) and this is not same as my issue)

For eg if I got `a` as:

```
[(0, 13, 'order1'), (14, 27, 'order2'), (14, 27, 'order2.1'), 
 (0, 13, 'order1'), (28, 41, 'order3')]
```

I want the output as:

```
[(14, 27, 'order2'), (0, 13, 'order1'), (28, 41, 'order3')]
```

I am getting the desired output using below code.

```
for e, i in enumerate(a):
    r = [True if i[0] == k[0] and e != j else False for j, k in enumerate(a)]
    if any(r):
        a.pop(e)
pprint(a)
```

Is there a better or more pythonic way to achieve the same?

Comment: If you find two duplicates, say ` (14, 27, 'order2')` and  `(14, 27, 'order2.1')`, how do you know which 3rd item to use, `'order2'` or `'order2.1'`?

Comment: The 2nd item in the tuple doesn't matter?

Comment: @JoePatten does not really matter, I can choose any one of them

Comment: It's a generally *awful* idea to alter a list *while* you're iterating through it.

Comment: @prune not really (would the solution be different if I would say yes?) and I agree/know its an _awfullest_ of an idea to alter the list hence this post, looking for "better/more pythonic" solution.

Comment: Yes, the solution would be different; you'd have to keep both (0, 0, "a") and (0, 1, "b") in that case.

Comment: Your given solution fails.  Try `a = [(14, 27, 'order1'), (14, 27, 'order2'), (14, 27, 'order2.1'), (14, 27, 'order1'), (28, 41, 'order3')]`

Comment: @Prune ok lets say it doesn't matter, if the 1st item matches then its dup, we will not check 2nd item.

Comment: Great; you have two viable answers, covering what I would have suggested.  Up-vote as appropriate, choose a "best" answer, and move on to your next coding need.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way is keying a dict off whatever you want to dedupe by, for example:

```
>>> a = [(0, 13, 'order1'), (14, 27, 'order2'), (14, 27, 'order2.1'), (0, 13, 'order1'), (28, 41, 'order3')] 
>>> print(*{tup[:2]: tup for tup in a}.values()) 
(0, 13, 'order1') (14, 27, 'order2.1') (28, 41, 'order3')
```

This is *O(n)* time complexity, superior to *O(n log n)* groupby based approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid modifying your list in place while iterating over it. Instead, you can use the popular [`itertools` `unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), also available in 3rd party [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen). Just use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) in the `key` argument:

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
from operator import itemgetter

res = list(unique_everseen(L, key=itemgetter(0, 1)))
```

This solution takes O(*n*) time, but is generally *less* efficient than a dictionary-based solution, although it is arguably clearer in its intention.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first element of each group in a grouped, sorted list:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

a = [(0, 13, 'order1'), (14, 27, 'order2'), (14, 27, 'order2.1'), (0, 13, 'order1'), (28, 41, 'order3')]

result = [list(g)[0] for k, g in groupby(sorted(a), key=itemgetter(0))]
print(result)
```